# Wion32's HttpSendRequest : ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STAT

Tags: wininet

I have C++ Win32 app that uses HttpSendRequest to request some URL (via https). It worked OK earlier; but then errors ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE began happen. Why these ones? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across something very similar recently. It suggests that your HttpOpenRequest has either failed or **not yet completed**, or during the HttpSendRequest() call the connection died for some reason (SSL handshake problems, Certificate problems, or just simple TCP connection problems).

I specifically saw the problem when developing an app using the asynchronous WinINET process, and my calls to HttpQueryInfo and InternetReadFile were failing with that return code.

In my case, I wasn't correctly waiting for the async notifications from HttpSendRequest to be received before calling the other methods, and also in cases where I wasn't correctly dealing with failures during the connection.

I know its a year late, but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems trivial but,
did you have flag INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE in making HttpOpenRequest?
as described in:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168151

For I myself was stuck here for hours until I found above knowledge base entry.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on Windows XP for HTTPS connection (all flags correct) for the HTTP2 server endpoint, I wonder if it can't properly handle HTTP2 connection or the certificate.